# betweenness/ igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

i work with igraph in python.I want to find the "betweeness" and "closeness" of my graph.
It return the same error even my weight was positive.

```
Gm.betweenness(directed=False, weights = Gm.es["weight"], nobigint=False)
```

---

```
InternalError                             
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-cd86830ce27a> in <module>
----> 1 Gm.betweenness(directed=False, weights = Gm.es["weight"], nobigint=False)

InternalError: Error at c:\projects\python-igraph\vendor\build\igraph\igraph-0.8.0-msvc\src\centrality.c:1641: Weight vector must be positive, Invalid value
```

Comment: Without your data, it will be very hard for anyone to answer. Can you provide your graph?

Comment: My data is a datafarme, contains 3 colunms (number of someone who calls, number of the receiving person, and the weight, was calculated by different factors) and 3millions rows. i convert it to graph then i want to calculate its closeness & betweeness mesures.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible some of your edge weights are zero. Even though the error says "Weight vector must be positive" what it really means is all the elements of the weight vector has to be > 0. Try filtering out any zeroes or replace your 0s with a 0.0001.